# Oracle - cannot alter procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, dbup

When DbUp executes the following SQL script, I get an error as shown further down:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INVOICE_DELETE
    (PAR_INVOICE_ID IN NUMBER)
AS 
BEGIN   
    DELETE FROM INVOICE_SECT_ACCOUNTING_DATA
    WHERE INVOICE_ID = PAR_INVOICE_ID;
    
    DELETE FROM INVOICE
    WHERE INVOICE_ID = PAR_INVOICE_ID;
    
    COMMIT;
      
END INVOICE_DELETE;
```

> Oracle error code: 1; Number -2147467259; Message: 904
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005):
> ORA-00904: "PAR_INVOICE_ID": niepoprawny identyfikator

Comment: Can you show the definition of the tables?  Also "niepoprawny identyfikator" - please translate to English  thanks

Comment: ORA-00904 is "invalid identifier"

Comment: The error states that it was unable to find the column. Cross-check the tables INVOICE_SECT_ACCOUNTING_DATA and INVOICE for column "INVOICE_ID"

Comment: [The documentation](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported-databases/) suggests DbUp doesn't support Oracle. I suspect either the PL/SQL syntax or (maybe) the blank line is confusing it, and it's effectively running one of the `delete` statements - in that context the error would make sense, as the table doesn't have a column called `par_invoice_id`.

Comment: By the way, you can't alter a procedure. You can only create or replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DbUp-Oracle has 2 buiders: OracleDatabaseWithDefaultDelimiter and OracleDatabaseWithSemicolonDelimiter - https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp/pull/335.

My bad because I used OracleDatabaseWithSemicolonDelimiter. So DbUp splits my procedure into pieces.